# Cannot copy the data output of an SQL query into clipboard with PgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I run a single SQL request on `PgAdmin 4.6`.

```
select nom, sectionnaf, sum(nombresalaries) as nombre_salaries from activites_des_communes where epci = '200069532' group by nom, sectionnaf
order by nom, nombre_salaries desc;
```

it displays the accurate columns and results on *Data Output*.

*Data Output* allows me to select all the 400 rows displayed with an arrow on the top left corner, but not to copy them into clipboard or do anything else with them. Any click with the mouse has no effect (right click or left click) and I can't figure how it is intented to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data Output allows you to select all the rows displayed with an arrow on the top left corner, Now you need to click on `Copy button` to copy them into Clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/query_tool.html#):

> The Query Tool allows you to:
>
> [...]
>
> - Save the data displayed in the output panel to a CSV file.

You have to use menu items on the main menu of the Query Tool bar for this.

Comment: Your answer is a useful one, that allows me to have a workaround.
But it doesn't send the content on the clipboard if this is what the user wants. And we are in 2019...